# Back to the designated point with anchor

Tags: ruby

How can i do stuff like that in ruby:

```
#  => ANCHOR GO BACK HERE
...some code
f = 0
while f == 0
 ... some code
f = 1
end
# if [condition] => ANCHOR FROM HERE
```

It's sth like goto in pascal i belive, but i'm not sure.
I want to go back to the "Anchor" in code when certain condition happen.
Could somebody help me with that?

Comment: Just a side note, I think you meant `while f == 0` (note the double equals) ... otherwise this will run forever. Anyway, Ruby doesn't have goto.

Comment: I do not understand your question. When you skip the `f = 1` line it would basically jump back to the line in question and repeat the block. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Hello, i did some changes, now it's should be clear for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is with a loop:

```
loop do
  # ...some code
  f = 0
  while f == 0
    ... some code
    f = 1
  end
  break unless some_condition
end
```

So, the loop will continue *unless* the condition is met.